# Adding a current/active state to a jQuery scroller/Side Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, state, scroller

We have a side menu in place that is based off the code found here on google docs.

http://code.google.com/mobile/articles/webapp_fixed_ui.html

We have it in place and its working nicely, what I'm wanting to do is enable a current/active state so when they select a menu item it remains the slightly darker color.

I've been research current active states on stackoverflow and I don't see anything that could assist me

IF someone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement your requested functionality. You could:

- attach a javascript function to the click event of your navigation links that toggles active state (suitable if you're navigating through named anchors on the current page)
- determine the current page on the server side (with PHP for example) and set an active css class to the current navigation link
- use css and markup as in the article that alpaca lips nao mentions

If you describe your situation in more detail I'm sure we could guide to an appropriate solution.